# PG 0074360/12 in un'ordinanza del Comune di Forlì

Tags: word-meaning, translation

I would like to ask you something about an abbreviation that appears in a "ordinanza del Comune di Forlì". This document (I'm afraid I can't show you, because I haven't found it on Internet) explains the ban on traffic during some days of the week in order to stop polluting the city.

At the beginning of the document appears "Atto 427/2012" and "PG 0074360/12". I haven't found what does PG refers to in this kind of document, do you have any idea?

Comment: All documents written by Italian municipes are public so you can post here. This is the link of your document: http://www.comune.forli.fc.it/upload/forli/gestionedocumentale/ordinanza%20LUN%20VEN_784_27497.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of abbreviation stands for ***Protocollo Generale*** (Protocol section registry) which is where all inbound (received) and outbound (sent) documents by this Italian public administration (Comune) must be registered according to the law.

So it means that the document regarding "Atto 427/2012" can be found on this registry with the sequential number PG 0074360/12, where /12 usually refers to the year when the record has been added to the registry.

Comment: Ho trovato un riferimento in questo documento: http://www.comune.bologna.it/media/files/manuale_allegato_delibera_pg176499.pdf a pag. 7 art.5